# How to make avatar with bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, avatar

I am using Bootstrap 5 and I want to make avatar with different icons in it (simmilar as letter avatar). So, I need to have placeholder and inside that placeholder i need to add the icon. Something like the code:

```
<div width="30%" height="30%" class="bg-info rounded-circle">
<span>
{Icon here}
</span>
</div>
```

But this is not working.
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Can you give any examples? You can also create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this

Comment: @I_love_vegetables I need to do something like letter avatar, but if i use bootstrap  `<div width="30%" height="30%" class="bg-info rounded-circle"><span>NG<span /> <div />`  - The background color is not changing and the borders arent getting rounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a ready-to-use stylesheet for bootstrap called bootstrap-avatar at github:
[bootstrap-avatar](https://github.com/ghoststead/bootstrap-avatar)

The other way is using plain css to build it. It is quite easy by the way.
Here is an example: [Building avatars using css](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_avatar.asp)

Also, if you are using inline css, you have to wrap it into style like that:

```
<div style="width:30%;" class="bg-info rounded-circle">
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this now

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [**documentation**](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/avatar/) I've used to create the solution.

Check out this snippet - I think this is exactly what you are trying to achieve.

[**Bootstrap Avatar with Icon**](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/standard/filipkapusta/3615147)

[image: Bootstrap Avatar]

The key is to set a fixed width and add the `.rounded-circle` class - but you also have to properly align the icon within the rounded div.

This example is from a **[GitHub repository dedicated to Bootstrap Avatars](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-avatar)**.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is how I normally use it:

Step 1) Add HTML:

```
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
```

Step 2) Add CSS:
Set a matching height and width that looks good, and use the border-radius property to add rounded corners to an image. 50% will make the image circular:

```
 .avatar {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```